# Error Installing Zip AND unzip error?

Tags: twrp, magisk

### Hardware details:

poco x3 NFC

### Issue:

I'm trying to install some external modules.  Getting errors from Magisk and TWRP.

I've verified the integrity of the modules after having re-downloaded them: looked at them on a PC and everything is intact and as-expected.  But when I try to install via TWRP, I get the error seen in the image below: "`error installing zip`".

So, am I missing a step to installing a magisk module?  Should I reinstall my OS and install the modules simultaneously?  Somehow, I would like to get a lot of Magisk modules onto my phone.

[image: A photo of the error reading script succeeded: result was [1.000000] newline. updating partition details... newline. ...done newline. installing zip file semi-quote external underbar sd forwardslash styxOS dash 1 dot 6 dash Athena dash surya dash official dash 20210713 dash 1925 dot zip semiquote. newline. error installing zip file, repeats name of zip file seen just before, newline. updating partition details... newline. ...done]

I get the error above in TWRP.

"`unzip error`" from Magisck.

Comment: Try with [Fox manager](https://github.com/Fox2Code/FoxMagiskModuleManager). This is the preferred way since some modules don't play well with TWRP from what others say. I don't have TWRP for my device and never had an issue with Fox manager//You can easily search for modules too // You can report this to the developer of TWRP

Comment: Fox's Magisk Module Manager does not work on Poco X3 NFC.  Tried the latest 3 versions.

Comment: I made an error.  The 2nd to last version worked properly.  I somehow skipped over it while installing old versions.  Feel free to post as an answer--

Comment: Thanks. Could you please self-answer? Problems you faced and how it was overcome are best known to you and these details may help someone else!